# Am I Using (Scala) Generics Correctly?

Tags: scala, generics, nested-generics

I currently have code with structure like the following:

```
object Example {
  val doctor : Healer[Cancer]   = new Doctor
  val parent : Healer[Cold]     = new Parent
  val generic: Healer[Sickness] = new Generic

  def cure(sickness: Sickness): Boolean = sickness match {
    case cancer: Cancer => doctor.cure(cancer)
    case cold  : Cold   => parent.cure(cold)
    case other          => generic.cure(other)
  }
}

class Sickness
class Cancer extends Sickness
class Cold   extends Sickness
// other sicknesses

abstract class Healer[A <: Sickness] {
  def cure(sickness: A): Boolean
}

abstract class Treatment[A <: Sickness] {
  def cure(sickness: A): Boolean
}

class Doctor[A <: Cancer] extends Healer[A] {
  val treatments: List[Treatments[A]] = List(
    new Chemotherapy,
    new Surgery,
    new HopesAndPrayers
  )

  def cure(sickness: A): Boolean = {
    // ... choose a treatment
    treatment.cure(sickness)
  }
}

class Chemotherapy[A <: Cancer] extends Treatment[A] {
  def cure(cancer: A): Boolean = {
    // without generics, needs a check for Cancer
  }
}

// other Healers (e.g. Parent, Generic) and other Treatments (e.g. BedRest, HealthyFood)
```

Is this how generics are properly/normally used? Should/could I have isolated it to `Treatment` and/or `Healer`? If yes, how?

To explain further, this started out without generics, but when I started to create subclasses of `Treatments` such as `Chemotherapy`, I ended up with `cure(sickness: Sickness)` methods that contain `sickness match { case cancer: Cancer => ... }`. It seemed like if I had a class `SomeSpecificTreatment` that only dealt with `SomeSpecificSickness`, it would make sense for it to have a method `cure(sickness: SomeSpecificSickness)` rather than `cure(sickness: Sickness)`.

So I added generics to `Treatment`, and they consequently made their way up to `Example`. When this happens, I usually feel like I'm doing something wrong. I'm particularly suspicious of `Example#cure`. With more subclasses of `Sickness`, the list of cases can get pretty long and I instinctively feel like it could be done differently and better (can it?). I've considered using a `Map` to do something like `healers.getOrElse(sickness.getClass, generic)`, but it wouldn't behave the same as pattern matching types and I usually have difficulty with nested generics anyway.

Since this could come up: I don't have control over `Sickness` or its subclasses and I can't change the signature of `Example#cure`

Comment: In my humble opinion this looks allright. Of course you are effectively using the same call `healer.cure(sickness)`, but that is unavoidable, because for every type of sickness you are using a different kind of healer. Think about it this way: A cancer does not define which doctor should heal it, it can be *any* doctor. You (as the patient) have to decide which doctor to use. Only when you can be sure that there is always exactly one `Healer` for each `Sickness` you can omit such a mapping. This could be done with `implicit`s or `object`s.

Answer (score 2):

I typically find that when designing related class hierarchies sooner or later something comes along that breaks the model and ends up being hacked around.

Have you considered using Typeclasses which are a very common pattern in functional programming languages.

```
case class Cancer(name: String)
case class Cold(name: String)

sealed trait Healer[S] {
  def name: String
  def cure(sickness: S): Unit = println(s"$name curing $sickness")
}

implicit val oncologist = new Healer[Cancer] {
  val name = "Oncologist"
}

implicit val mum = new Healer[Cold] {
  val name = "Mum"
}

def cure[S : Healer](sickness: S) = { 
  val healer = implicitly[Healer[S]]  
  healer.cure(sickness)
}

scala> cure(Cancer("Lung cancer"))
Oncologist curing Cancer(Lung cancer)

scala> cure(Cold("Flu"))
Mum curing Cold(Flu)
```

Otherwise unrelated types can be a member of a Typeclass which defines some sort of common behaviour for example sorting.

We may for example want healers for unrelated conditions Cancer, Burns and BrokenLeg that may not fit into a nice class hierarchy. Another advantage is that we can limit the scope of a Typeclass. Healer may make sense in a hospital where we want to cure a patient. In an insurance company we may interested in something else such as cost of treatment for a condition.

Comment: Would this still work if I want a fallback `Healer[Sickness]`? I can't change the signature of `Example#cure`, so even with `Example.cure(new Cancer)`, the compiler just sees the `Cancer` instance as a `Sickness` instance then ignores the `Healer[Cancer]` I have and resolves to the `Healer[Sickness]`. I should mention I'm still pretty new to implicit conversions/parameters. I'd only used implicit conversions for the first time a few days ago and hadn't even read the docs on implicit parameters prior to reading your reply. Maybe I'm using them wrong? +1 for making me read the docs though

Comment: You would define a type, lets call it Sickness and define an implicit val of type Healer[Sickness]